# Use Nlog to log context info of Asp.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nlog

I've two separate tables to log user activity and errors in asp.net web Api.
Here's my Activity Log table:
[image: ActivityLog]

To store the Log information in the table, Here's the Nlog.config setting.

```xml
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database" keepConnection="true" useTransactions="true"
             dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient" commandType="Text"
        connectionString="data source=XXXXX;initial catalog=XXXXX;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX"
        commandText="INSERT INTO [dbo].[ActivityLog]([PageName],[MethodName],[IPAddress],[RequestedUrl],[IsAuthenticated],[UserName],[Date]) VALUES(@PageName,@MethodName,@IPAddress,@RequestedUrl,@IsAuthenticated,@UserName,@Date)">
  <parameter name="@PageName" layout="" />
  <parameter name="@MethodName" layout="" />
  <parameter name="@IPAddress" layout=""/>
  <parameter name="@RequestedUrl" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}"/>
  <parameter name="@IsAuthenticated" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}:isAuthenticated"/>
  <parameter name="@UserName" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}"/>
  <parameter name="@Date" layout="${date:s}"/>
</target>
```

For the Page Name parameter I need the Web API Controller Name, and for Method Name parameter I need the action Method of the Controller that is called.
Also I need to know whether the user is authenticated or not.

Now Kindly let me know the settings defined in the Nlog config file are correct or not and also how to pass values to the other parameters.

Comment: Is your current setup not working or do you miss some values?

Comment: For the Page Name parameter I need the Web API Controller Name, and for Method Name parameter I need the action Method of the Controller that is called. Also I need to know whether the user is authenticated or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All possible layout renderers could be found [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers). 
You could use the following renderers:

- Web API Controller Name: `${aspnet-MVC-Controller}`
- Method Name: you could use the `${callsite}` or `${aspnet-mvc-action}`
- isAuthenticated: `${identity:isAuthenticated}`

PS:

- All parameters to the database target are string parameters

Comment: I'm not using.net core. I'm working on.net 4.6, will the above solution work for me? And also could you please let me know how to log error to dB in asp.net web API using nlog.

Comment: Thank you, could you please let me know how to log all the error/exception related information in the dB using nlog in asp.net web API (.net framework 4.6).

Comment: ,thank you very much. Now,I'm able to successfully log the Info and Exceptions to dB. But, I need the value of parameters passed to the action method in ASP.NET Web API to be logged as well. Could you please suggest a way! And, I need logging enabled or disabled based on setting in web.config file. Kindly help